# AS3 How am I calling a function from a class on the timeline?

Tags: function, actionscript-3, class

How would I be calling the following public function from a class file called Digit:

```
public class Digit extends MovieClip {
public function flipTo(num:String):void {
        _number = num;
        _nextDigit[TOP].t_num.text = num;
        _nextDigit[BOTTOM].t_num.text = num;

        // flip down the top of the digit to the halfway point
        TweenLite.to(_currentDigit[TOP], .15, {scaleY:0, ease:Linear.easeNone});
        // flip the next digit bottom down 
        TweenLite.to(_nextDigit[BOTTOM], .3, {scaleY:1, onComplete: flipComplete,  ease: Bounce.easeOut});
    }
}
```

On the main timeline I am trying to call this function to initiate the flip animation when I need to like so:

```
function clockShow(){
clock.visible = true;
var digit:Digit = new Digit(); 
digit.flipTo(); 
}
```

But I am receiving this error: Scene 1, Layer 'as', Frame 1, Line 21    1136: Incorrect number of arguments.  Expected 1.

Line 21 refers to `digit.flipTo();`

Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: The function belongs to a class (it's a method), so you need an instance of that class to be able to call it. Do you have an instance?

Comment: Thanks Fygo, the class is "Digit", but I am not sure what you mean. How would I be able to create an instance of that class on the timeline, so I would be able to call that function? Thanks!

Comment: show us how you use it.

Comment: var digit:Digit = new Digit();
digit.flipTo("abc");
That's how you could use a method of a class. But it is difficult to see what you are trying to do there, really.

Comment: Thanks Fygo, I revised my post based on your suggestion, but I must still be missing something here.

Comment: Your method `flipTo` expects one argument of the type `String`, like `flipTo("hello")`. Calling it without parameters will lead to an error such as the one you're experiencing now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should import that class

```
import Digit;
```

as you say "*I tried to call flipTo(); from the root timeline...*" your function should be static.if you make your function static, you don't need to write `var digit:Digit = new Digit();`but if you want to set more digits,don't set it to static.

```
public static function flipTo(num:String):void {...
```

now you can call it from the main timeline:

```
Digit.flipTo(myString);
```

I H☻P E this helps

Comment: What if there are more than 1 Digit? What if the Digits represent a digital clock? The static function wouldn't work then.

Comment: He can change the name of this class or the other "Digit".

Comment: @HITMAN so he would create a class for every Digit then?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand "every Digit".

Comment: @HITMAN your solution fails as soon as there are more than 1 Digit, your suggested solution to this is to change the name of the classes, which in turn means that for every Digit, there has to be a new class. If there are 5 digits, you'd have to have 5 classes. Making this method static is not a good idea. It basically abuses classes as objects and fails for the mentioned reason.

Comment: Yeah this is not a very useful answer and barely provide a reliable answer. PO accepted it as the right answer cos he doesn't know better. I would be surprised if PO managed to make anything work with this answer or that PO has written the method and class he refers to.

Comment: Yes I understand and changed my answer.but why do you say that? maybe he wants just one digit.

Comment: Nobody is forming an union against you, we just pointed out a flaw in your answer. And considering that the PO uses a function called `clockShow` and his `flipTo` function seems to change a single Digit (as the name of the class implies), it's pretty reasonable to assume that PO wants to realize a digital clock of some kind. Your answer isn't wrong per say, but it will lead to much more errors down the line.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to instantiate a class only once. It's not to be considered a special case "oh, this only exists once, so let's make everything related to it static". In an object oriented environment it's best to think in objects first. With static functions you are limited to manipulating other objects like utility functions. There's no `Digit` object that can be added to the display for example.

Answer (score 0):

> But I am receiving this error: Scene 1, Layer 'as', Frame 1, Line 21 1136: Incorrect number of arguments. Expected 1.

Well, it's because your method is expecting a parameter:

```
public function flipTo(num:String):void
```

As you declared it, your method needs a String to be passed to it. In your example code:

```
var digit:Digit = new Digit(); 
digit.flipTo();
```

You are not passing anything. That's pretty much what the error message says.